# Custom Control - Solution ideas?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, custom-controls

I have a custom user control that inherits asp:Repeater and get's 'initialized' on first run - it finds the children controls (in repeater item template) and creates a SQL table based on a tablename property provided as an attribute on the control. To know not to initialize it again, I simply check for the table (this has issues).

My problem is, tablename property **should not** be changed after initialization, days or even weeks later.

How can I tie a readonly property and value to a particular control only after initialization?

Sounds pretty tricky, maybe impossible. Out of the box solution?

**EDIT:** Thx Dennis - I'm not talking about modification during runtime

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem, could you show some code?

Comment: No code, trying to find a solution before I start coding.

Comment: Are you talking of custom controls or user controls? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893667 I assume custom control in spite of your title.

Comment: Add a set method to the property and manage it to allow setting a value only if it's null

Comment: @timmah: if your control creates the tables itself, the sql/sp could check if the table already exists, if so, do nothing or return a custom exception.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - exactly what I've done Tim, good suggestion and good name :)

Answer (score 3):

Set the _tablename only if it hasn't been set before:

```
Private _tablename As String

Public Property TableName() As String
    Get
        Return _tablename
    End Get
    Private Set(ByVal value As String)
       If String.IsNullOrEmpty(_tablename) Then 
           _tablename = value
       End If
    End Set
End Property
```

C#

```
private string _tablename;

public string Tablename {
    get { return _tablename; }
    private set {
        if String.IsNullOrEmpty(_tablename)
            _tablename = value;
    }
}
```

To make the field `_tablename` itself inaccessible once it has been set, you can declare it `ReadOnly`. But be aware that it then can only set during object contruction. Initialization would then have to occur in the constructor:

```
Private ReadOnly _tablename As String

Public ReadOnly Property Tablename() As String
    Get
        Return _tablename
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub New()
    ' This must happen here, _tablename is readonly from anywhere else:
    _tablename = "yourtablename" 
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a VB.NET question. Edit: added to your answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter true, must have overlooked the tag. I see you edited my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: In a quick test I have implemented this code already. Doesn't stop a user from changing the property later.

Comment: @timmah.faase I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Using the code above, the property is only accessible from inside the class and sets the variable only if it hasn't been set before.

Comment: @DennisTraub I have a custom control, put it in my page, setting TableName (public property) to "xyz". I build the site, run it and the code creates an SQL table with the name "xyz" - I want to try and stop a developer the next day, day after, 2 weeks time to not change TableName now that the SQL table has been created in my code. Is that possible?

Comment: @timmah.faase oh, now I understand, you're not talking about modification during runtime but through changing the code itself? I'm afraid that is more of a process issue and can't be enforced through the code itself.

Comment: @DennisTraub - thx Dennis - exactly. Oh well, appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

How about inisitalising the User Control passing the table name in the constructor.  Create the table in an init function (or the constructor if you wish).

Then do:

```
Private _tablename As String (Initialised at construction)

Public Property TableName() As String
Get
    Return _tablename
End Get

End Property
```